# Why is a second "tmpfs" parameter necessary when mounting a tmpfs?

Tags: linux, unix, mount, documentation, tmpfs

Excerpted from the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt)

> So 'mount -t tmpfs -o size=10G,nr_inodes=10k,mode=700 tmpfs /mytmpfs'
>   will give you tmpfs instance on /mytmpfs which can allocate 10GB
>   RAM/SWAP in 10240 inodes and it is only accessible by root.

Please note the command line:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=10G,nr_inodes=10k,mode=700 tmpfs /mytmpfs
```

What makes me confused is the second `tmpfs`. The [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) says nothing on the option `tmpfs`, what does it mean?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not an option – **it's the device name.**

Remember that the syntax for `mount(8)` is:

```
mount [-t fstype] [-o options] device mountpoint
```

So even for filesystems that don't correspond to a specific device, you still need to give a dummy name, whether it's `none` or `tmpfs` or `fluttershyfs`.

Comment: I had to google 'fluttershy', and was not undisappointed.

Comment: Extra bonus for mentioning fluttershyfs.